# Compression image when uploading

Tags: resize

i want to upload image without limit size but auto compress image size when uploading..just the image will automatically resize to small size when processing submit button. how to do it?

```
<?php
  $eror       = false;
  $folder     = './upload/';
//file type
  $file_type  = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp');
  if(isset($_POST['btnUpload'])){
$file_name  = $_FILES['data_upload']['name'];
//search ext file
$explode    = explode('.',$file_name);
$extension    = $explode[count($explode)-1];
 //check file type
if(!in_array($extension,$file_type)){
    $eror   = true;
    $msg .= 'File type is not recognized<br />';
}
if($eror == true){
    echo '<div id="eror">'.$msg.'</div>';
}
else{
    //start upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data_upload']['tmp_name'], $folder.$file_name)){
        //post to database
        $sql = mysql_query('insert into file_upload(Filename,Detail,Folder,DateUpload) values ("'.$file_name.'", "'.$_POST['desc'].'",
                              "'.$folder.'", "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'")');
        echo '<div id="msg">Uploade '.$file_name.' is success</div>';
    } else{
        echo "Upload eror";
    }
    }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: I can see some erors in your code. Pun intended.

Comment: only need help for add funtion to compress size...

Answer (score 0):

Enabling unlimited filesize is not recommended since one user can drain all your server resources.

Nevertheless you cannot compress the image while uploading with PHP (at least not to my knowledge) because the hole request has to be finished before it is passed from the webserver to PHP.

You can however compress the file after it was uploaded. But this question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819524/a-very-good-php-image-resize-script-suggestion) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650572/resize-image-php) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Comment: yes i know....and compress the file after it was uploaded is not good idea. thanks for suggestion