# How to resize uploaded image in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form with upload image field. How to resize the recently uploaded image to desired size?
My current form is :

```
<?php
class Application_Form_User extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $this->setAction("");
    $this->setMethod("post");

    $element = new Zend_Form_Element_File('photo');
    $element->setLabel('Upload an image:')
            ->setValueDisabled(true);
    $this->addElement($element, 'photo');
    $element->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
    // limit to 1000K
    $element->addValidator('Size', false, 1024000);
    // only JPEG, PNG, and GIFs
    $element->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif');
    $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'submit');
    $submit->setLabel('Save');
    $this->addElement($submit);
}
```

}

And my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form=new Application_Form_User();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $file=pathinfo($form->photo->getFileName());
            $form->photo->addFilter('Rename', PUBLIC_PATH.'/images/'.uniqid().time().'.'.$file['extension']);
            if ($form->photo->receive()) {
                $this->view->photo=pathinfo($form->photo->getFileName());
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form=$form;
}
```

Can somebody provide me with an example? How can i use plugins like php thumbnailer or similar plugin to resize the uploaded image?

Comment: Give this class a go - https://gist.github.com/880506

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911293/resize-image-on-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skoch_Filter_File_Resize works. It is a custom filter: http://eliteinformatiker.de/2011/09/02/thumbnails-upload-and-resize-images-with-zend_form_element_file/

```
<?php
// Skoch/Filter/File/Resize.php
/**
 * Zend Framework addition by skoch
 * 
 * @category   Skoch
 * @package    Skoch_Filter
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 * @author     Stefan Koch <cct@stefan-koch.name>
 */

/**
 * @see Zend_Filter_Interface
 */
require_once 'Zend/Filter/Interface.php';

/**
 * Resizes a given file and saves the created file
 *
 * @category   Skoch
 * @package    Skoch_Filter
 */
class Skoch_Filter_File_Resize implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    protected $_width = null;
    protected $_height = null;
    protected $_keepRatio = true;
    protected $_keepSmaller = true;
    protected $_directory = null;
    protected $_adapter = 'Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_Gd';

    /**
     * Create a new resize filter with the given options
     *
     * @param Zend_Config|array $options Some options. You may specify: width, 
     * height, keepRatio, keepSmaller (do not resize image if it is smaller than
     * expected), directory (save thumbnail to another directory),
     * adapter (the name or an instance of the desired adapter)
     * @return Skoch_Filter_File_Resize An instance of this filter
     */
    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        if ($options instanceof Zend_Config) {
            $options = $options->toArray();
        } elseif (!is_array($options)) {
            require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Filter_Exception('Invalid options argument provided to filter');
        }

        if (!isset($options['width']) && !isset($options['height'])) {
            require_once 'Zend/Filter/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Filter_Exception('At least one of width or height must be defined');
        }

        if (isset($options['width'])) {
            $this->_width = $options['width'];
        }
        if (isset($options['height'])) {
            $this->_height = $options['height'];
        }
        if (isset($options['keepRatio'])) {
            $this->_keepRatio = $options['keepRatio'];
        }
        if (isset($options['keepSmaller'])) {
            $this->_keepSmaller = $options['keepSmaller'];
        }
        if (isset($options['directory'])) {
            $this->_directory = $options['directory'];
        }
        if (isset($options['adapter'])) {
            if ($options['adapter'] instanceof Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_Abstract) {
                $this->_adapter = $options['adapter'];
            } else {
                $name = $options['adapter'];
                if (substr($name, 0, 33) != 'Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_') {
                    $name = 'Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_' . ucfirst(strtolower($name));
                }
                $this->_adapter = $name;
            }
        }

        $this->_prepareAdapter();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate the adapter if it is not already an instance
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareAdapter()
    {
        if ($this->_adapter instanceof Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_Abstract) {
            return;
        } else {
            $this->_adapter = new $this->_adapter();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Defined by Zend_Filter_Interface
     *
     * Resizes the file $value according to the defined settings
     *
     * @param  string $value Full path of file to change
     * @return string The filename which has been set, or false when there were errors
     */
    public function filter($value)
    {
        if ($this->_directory) {
            $target = $this->_directory . '/' . basename($value);
        } else {
            $target = $value;
        }

        return $this->_adapter->resize($this->_width, $this->_height,
            $this->_keepRatio, $value, $target, $this->_keepSmaller);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
// Skoch/Filter/File/Resize/Adapter/Abstract.php
/**
 * Zend Framework addition by skoch
 * 
 * @category   Skoch
 * @package    Skoch_Filter
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 * @author     Stefan Koch <cct@stefan-koch.name>
 */


/**
 * Resizes a given file and saves the created file
 *
 * @category   Skoch
 * @package    Skoch_Filter
 */
abstract class Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_Abstract
{
    abstract public function resize($width, $height, $keepRatio, $file, $target, $keepSmaller = true);

    protected function _calculateWidth($oldWidth, $oldHeight, $width, $height)
    {
        // now we need the resize factor
        // use the bigger one of both and apply them on both
        $factor = max(($oldWidth/$width), ($oldHeight/$height));
        return array($oldWidth/$factor, $oldHeight/$factor);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
// Skoch/Filter/File/Resize/Adapter/Gd.php
/**
 * Zend Framework addition by skoch
 * 
 * @category   Skoch
 * @package    Skoch_Filter
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 * @author     Stefan Koch <cct@stefan-koch.name>
 */

require_once 'Skoch/Filter/File/Resize/Adapter/Abstract.php';

/**
 * Resizes a given file with the gd adapter and saves the created file
 *
 * @category   Skoch
 * @package    Skoch_Filter
 */
class Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_Gd extends
    Skoch_Filter_File_Resize_Adapter_Abstract
{
    public function resize($width, $height, $keepRatio, $file, $target, $keepSmaller = true)
    {
        list($oldWidth, $oldHeight, $type) = getimagesize($file);

        switch ($type) {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $source = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
        }

        if (!$keepSmaller || $oldWidth > $width || $oldHeight > $height) {
            if ($keepRatio) {
                list($width, $height) = $this->_calculateWidth($oldWidth, $oldHeight, $width, $height);
            }
        } else {
            $width = $oldWidth;
            $height = $oldHeight;
        }

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        imagealphablending($thumb, false);
        imagesavealpha($thumb, true);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $oldWidth, $oldHeight);

        switch ($type) {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                imagepng($thumb, $target);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                imagejpeg($thumb, $target);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                imagegif($thumb, $target);
                break;
        }
        return $target;
    }
}
```

---

```
$photo->addFilter(new Skoch_Filter_File_Resize(array(
    'width' => 200,
    'height' => 300,
    'keepRatio' => true,
)));
```

Comment: hi, I used this library and it works absolutely fine. But the uploaded images are rotated to left. what to do??